# Internet Explorer Cuts Off Phrase "Search Entire Store Here"

Tags: magento-1.9

search box with wording "Search Entire Store Here" shows fine in Chrome but only shows half of this phrase in Internet Explorer[image]

Comment: It is a  css problem. and it is general issue to fix by designer or programmer. no one can help you without showing your website.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a fixed height for that element and if that still doesn't work in IE maybe using `!important` would help. Or if 'height' property isn't what you're looking for, maybe the 'line-height' would do the trick.